# is it possible to get finder to automatically create a folder with the same icon as the parent parent folder?

Tags: finder, macos, folders, icon

I have a folder with a custom icon, and was wondering if there was any way I could get all folders within it to automatically get the same custom folder icon, that way I don't have to keep changing the icons and every time I create a new folder, it automatically gets applied?

Thanks